# Sequence in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create a sequence that gives value like 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 ... ??

Comment: Sequence is the value that will be unique, your requirement is not a sequence. Provide your exact requirement, will be easy to help you

Answer (score 6):

```
create sequence darshan
    start with 1
    maxvalue 1
    minvalue -1
    increment by 2
    nocache 
    cycle;
```

Comment: I forgot about `cycle`.